# Which application to draw flowcharts like this?

Tags: data-visualization, diagram, flowchart

What application can be used to draw a flowchart like this taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-c-standard-template-library-stl/). Does anybody know?

My operating system is Windows. Any other operating system is fine. A paid product is fine too :)

[image: Flowchart]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/) (formerly draw.io).  It is gratis (free of cost). I use it intensively as a software engineer to architect and design different workflows.

There is also a [desktop app](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases) for the same web tool.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Rami.  I hope you don't mind, but I changed the name of the site to reflect their new name.  Like you, I still remember it as "draw.io", but it looks like all their branding is now "diagrams.net".  Feel free to revert or modify my edit as you see appropriate.

Comment: Actually, that looks like an awesome software! Thanks =)

Comment: Now I realized there is a VS Code extension based on the software you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you try MS Visio, have a look at [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed). It's free, works on Windows as well and can also draw flowcharts.

[image: Flowchart with yEd]

You can adjust the colors etc. to make it look closer to Visio.

Downside: I needed to get used to its usability. It doesn't behave like I expected it would. Usually I accidentally draw a lot of more boxes than needed.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the graphics in question was made with [Microsoft Visio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/visio/flowchart-software). It's from Microsoft and available in 2019 Standard version for ~440 €. It works on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like Visio to me. Personally I use [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/), its a lot more than a drawing tool ...but it is a very good drawing tool.

Comment: Any reference to "Visual Paradigm", any price indication / free or proprietory?

Comment: It's not free, there are different product versions that range from "not much" to quite expensive.
www.visual-paradigm.com

Answer (score 1):

[Inspiration](https://www.inspiration-at.com/inspiration-10/) can do this. It costs £60.